# how can I make Imageview saved in imageview[]

Tags: android, arrays, imageview, android-imageview

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ImageView;

int x;
ImageView ivcircle;
ImageView[] ivstorecircle = new ImageView[4];

for(x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
{
    ivstorecircle[x] = ivcircle.setImageLevel(x+1);
}
```

why last sentince is wrong and how can I corect it

thank you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because setImageLevel returns void. 
You need to use setImageLevel before.

Also i am gona assume that all variable are not null when the loop begins.

```
int x;
ImageView ivcircle;
ImageView[] ivstorecircle = new ImageView[4];

for(x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
{
    ivcircle.setImageLevel(x+1);
    ivstorecircle[x] = ivcircle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imageview ivStart01..
Imageview ivStart02..
Imageview ivStart03..
Imageview ivStart04..
Imageview ivStart05..

ImageView[] imageViews;


void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...
imageViews = new ImageView[]{ivStart01, ivStart02, ivStart03, ivStart04, ivStart05};
```

Comment: While this might work, It's far better to add details explaining you answer. You can find more tips here: [answer]